# Elemento se deforma al moverlo con position absolute css

Tags: html, css, position

Soy nuevo en html/css, y he estado jugueteando con las positions hasta que me ha surgido esto:

Aquí está mi código. Todo va bien en un principio, pero cuando cambio la posición de la caja, en concreto left: 800px;, la caja se mueve hacia donde yo quiero pero a la vez se deforma, y se hace más estrecha. ¿Alguna idea?

```
<div id="caja2">
 <div class="cajas">
    
 <div class="etiqueta">
    <br>
    
      <header id="xd"> TÍTULO </header>
      <hr width="50%"> 
      <br>

      <p>Este texto es un mero ejemplo. Carece de cualquier tipo de valor. No transmite absolutamente nada. Son únicamente palabras encrucijadas de forma que respeten las normas del habla y la escritura. Puesto que estoy ejerciendo mi derecho a poder expresar aquello que sobrevuelta mi mente, tu estás en el tuyo de pulsar este botón.</p> <br>

    <a class="boton" href="#">Infórmate</a>
      
    
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>

#caja2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 800px;
}
```

Comment: ¿Solo tienes ese estilo **CSS**? o hay más estilos como ```.cajas``` y ```.etiqueta```. Diches que se hace más estrecha, pero no dices que resultado deseas obtener, que tengo algún ancho predeterminado o como.

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres. Funciona como es de esperarse, se va acomodando al ancho que le queda del lado derecho, si le pusieses una medida fija de ancho te desbordaria horizontalmente, lo cual no es muy deseado.